# What's the name of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$\frac{y''}{x}+\frac{y}{x}=0,$$ what do we call this equation at the point $x=0$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd call it a trap! Your equation is equivalent to $y''+y=0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,+\infty)$. Is there any reason why you want to exclude the single point $x=0$?

In some sense, $x=0$ is a "removable singular point" for the equation.

Comment: Singular point is what I wanted, thank you very much.